# How do I get out from the if loop and into the menu?

Tags: python, function, menu

so basically it seems I get stuck in an infinite if-loop inside the add_movies function, but I want the program to be able to switch back to the menu function if needed. It doesn't really seem to matter what's inside the user_choice string and I don't understand why. Thanks for any help.

```
import sys
movies_list = []


user_key = input("To add a movie enter 'add', to quit enter 'quit'")

def menu():

  while user_key != "quit":
        if user_key == "add":
            add_movies()
        elif user_key == "list":
          pass
        elif user_key == "quit":
          sys.exit()
        else:
          pass

def add_movies():
    user_choice = input("Would you like to add a movie to the list of movies? \n\n ENTER: ")
    if user_choice == "yes":
        movie_title = input("Great! Please enter the name of the movie title: ")
        director = input("Great! Please enter the name of the movie's director: ")
        year = input("Great! Please enter the name of the movie's release date: ")
        movies_list.append(
            {
                "movie_title": movie_title,
                "director": director,
                "year": year
            }
        )
        print("_________________________________________________________________________________________________")
#It's here where i can't get to the menu again even if i type "no"
    elif user_choice == "no":
        menu()

menu()
```

Comment: `if` doesn't start a loop. But how do you expect `menu` to do different things than before? The value of `user_key` didnt't change since you called it the last time.

Comment: @Matthias so you mean that the user_key still has "add" as a string when jumping back to the menu and then restarting the add_movies function? If so what do I do to fix this?

Comment: Don't use recursion to recall the function that's already running a while loop. You're just causing confusion.

Comment: move user_key inside of the menu() method

Comment: @khelwood recursion? What do you mean?

Comment: "recursion? What do you mean?" — menu calls add_movies, and add_movies calls menu. So menu is causing itself to be called again, inside itself. That is recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling menu recursively. Put the input prompt in the while loop.

```py
movies_list = []
def menu():

    while (user_key := input("To add a movie enter 'add', to quit enter 'quit'\n")) != "quit":
        if user_key == "add":
            add_movies()
        elif user_key == "list":
            pass
        elif user_key == "quit":
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass


def add_movies():
    user_choice = input(
        "Would you like to add a movie to the list of movies? \n\n ENTER: ")
    if user_choice == "yes":
        movie_title = input(
            "Great! Please enter the name of the movie title: ")
        director = input(
            "Great! Please enter the name of the movie's director: ")
        year = input(
            "Great! Please enter the name of the movie's release date: ")
        movies_list.append(
            {
                "movie_title": movie_title,
                "director": director,
                "year": year
            }
        )
        print("_________________________________________________________________________________________________")
# It's here where i can't get to the menu again even if i type "no"
    elif user_choice == "no":
        return


menu()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed it! Such an easy fix, sat with this for like 40 min o_0